# React JS state values are not updating immediately in next function calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);
   this.updateData=this.updateData.bid(this)        
   this.state = {
       data:{
          name:"current company",
          value:123
       }
   }
}

updateData(name, value){
   this.setState({
       data:{
         name:name,
         value:value
       }
   });
}

<button onClick={this.updateData("New Company", 890)} >Update Data</button>
```

**How to update the state variable values.**
*this.setstate is not updating the values*

Comment: Is it simply a typo?  this.updateData.bid(this) should be this.updateData.bind(this)?

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` should be this way:

```
onClick={() => this.updateData("New Company", 890)}
```

because you don't want to pass the returned value of `this.updateData` to the `onClick` but rather you want to call it when the button is clicked.

there's also a typo:

```
this.updateData=this.updateData.bid(this)
```

should be

```
this.updateData=this.updateData.bind(this)
```

Comment: Take into account the typo for the function bind as well, but this is what's causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 this.updateData=this.updateData.bid(this)
```

to

```
this.updateData=this.updateData.bind(this)
```

also

```
<button onClick={this.updateData("New Company", 890)} >Update Data</button>
```

to

```
<button onClick={() => this.updateData("New Company", 890)} >Update Data</button>
```

complete code should be

```
constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);
   this.updateData=this.updateData.bid(this)        
   this.state = {
       data:{
          name:"current company",
          value:123
       }
   }
}

updateData(name, value){
   this.setState({
       data:{
         name:name,
         value:value
       }
   });
}

<button onClick={this.updateData("New Company", 890)} >Update Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use call back function to update the state variable values.

```
updateData(name, value){
     this.setState({
         data:{
     name:name,
     value:value
        }
      }, () => {
    *** Next statements ***  
    });

console.log("Updated value", this.state.data.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 : this.updateData=this.updateData.bind(this) please spell bind
2 : onClick={() => this.updateData("New Company", 890)} add arrow func

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       data:{
          name:"current company",
          value:123
       }
   };
    this.updateData=this.updateData.bind(this)
  }
  
  updateData(name, value){
   this.setState({
       data:{
         name:name,
         value:value
       }
   });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}
        <button onClick={() => this.updateData("New Company", 890)}>Update Data</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```